# To prove or disprove an union of two subspaces is a subspace if and only if an intersection of them within them

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

Let $U$ and $V$ be subspaces of a vector space $W$.

Prove or disprove that $U \cup V$ is a subspace of $W$ if and only if

> $U \cap V \in \{U, V\}$

I am not sure what "$U \cap V \in \{U, V\}$" exactly means.

By the way, how to type Latex in here?

Comment: It is not clear whether your post asks to clarify the question or to answer it. If it asks for an answer, you should first [show your work](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), and/or look for a duplicate.

Comment: To type Latex, put dollar signs around the expressions.

Comment: As for the answer, you can find some duplicates inside this list: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=union+of+two+subspaces

Comment: @AnneBauval I am just asking a clarification for the question. Thank you sincerely.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$$U\cap V\in\{U,V\}$$` gives
$$U\cap V\in\{U,V\}$$which means:
$$U \cap V=U\quad\text{or}\quad U \cap V=V.$$

Comment: Thank you totally, I thought this symbol $\in$ means within or subset of before. Your answer did make myself clear.